# PHP function return string and variable

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins

I have a PHP function that has to return some string and print variables into the string. Now the function returns a string but does not print variable value.

```
function listShortcode ($id) {
    $i = $id;
    $html = "<h2>List number";
    $html .= $id;
    $html .= "</h2> <p>other</p>";
    
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: $i is never used, add a space after "number", but anyway this should work. 
Can you show also some output value after calling listShortCode(1200)? 
Maybe input $id is empty.

Comment: This works fine: https://3v4l.org/Y2mnN Check value of `$id`.

Comment: Your vague question has `wordpress` tagged.  Is this supposed to be a wordpress shortcode? is `$id` supposed to be a shortcode attribute that is passed from the shortcode?  Please include more details to your question, so that people can provide a reasonable answer.

Answer (score -2):

use signle quot's

```
function listShortcode ($id) {
$i = $id;
$html = '<h2>List number';
$html .= $id;
$html .= '</h2> <p>other</p>';

return $html;}
```